# What is the value of x-ray inspection of an assembled PCB?

Tags: soldering, pcb-assembly

I've heard discussion of x-ray inspection of assembled PCBs. I understand this to be useful for things like BGAs, where there's no other way to inspect all the solder joints under the package. Is it useful for other situations? Can it provide helpful information about visible solder joints? Other things? Or is xray inspection typically limited to boards or components with particular parameters? And if so limited, what are those parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it would be quite valuable for examination of multi-layer boards.

There are less obvious uses, some of which appear [HERE](http://www.home.agilent.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/Why_Where_What_How_When.pdf?&cc=US&lc=eng).  The bottom line is that Xrays are better than optical techniques at assessing the quality of a solder joint beyond presence or absence.  How important this is for any given application, given the higher cost of the imaging modality, comes down to failure-mode analysis, Pareto analysis, etc.